# Async function is called several times

Tags: javascript, html, api, asynchronous

I have an async function which I call when a user click on an li item.
I would like to have my API called once after the user clicked on the validate button. For that, I put an eventlisterner on this button which trigger the API call.

The thing is when a user enter a 4 digit pin code, the async function is called 4 times (with the exact same parameters, ex: 0000).

Please find the code below:

HTML :

```
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pinCode" placeholder="Code Pin">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <div id="container">  
              <ul id="keyboard">   
                  <li class="letter">1</li>  
                  <li class="letter">2</li>  
                  <li class="letter">3</li>  
                  <li class="letter clearl">4</li>  
                  <li class="letter">5</li>  
                  <li class="letter">6</li> 
                
                  <li class="letter clearl">7</li>  
                  <li class="letter ">8</li>  
                  <li class="letter">9</li>  
                  <li class="letter clearl"></li>  
                  <li class="letter">0</li>
                  <li class="letter"></li>
                  <li class="delete lastitem clearl"><</li>  
                  <li id="submitPinCode" class="return">Valider</li>
              </ul>  
            </div>
```

JS:

```
async function validateAccess(app, pin) {
    let response = await fetch(url +'/access/validate', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'app': app,
        'pin': pin
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }   
    });     
    let validateAccess = await response.json();
    return validateAccess;
};

function showModal(app) {
    $('#pinModal').modal('show')
    document.getElementById('keyboard').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var pinCode = document.getElementById('pinCode');
        var saisie = e.target.innerText;
        if (saisie == '<') {
            console.log('remove');
            const text = pinCode.value;
            const editedText = text.slice(0, -1);
            pinCode.value = editedText;
            return
        } else if (saisie != 'Valider') {
            pinCode.value += saisie;
            return
        };
        document.getElementById('submitPinCode').addEventListener('click', function() {
            validateAccess(app, pinCode.value).then((validateAccess) => {
                console.log(validateAccess);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't add event listeners inside other event listeners. Every time you click on `keyboard` you add another `click` listener on the submit button. So it will call `validateAccess` as many times as you clicked on `keyboard`.

Comment: It's also poor style to use the same name for functions and variables, it makes the code very confusing.

Comment: thanks, I will change the variable name.
Your solution did worked, I wasn't aware that you can add multiple event listeners identicals to the same element ! thanks again

Comment: The function name begins with "add", not "set" or "replace". So every time you call it, you add another listener.